# c++: what does `typedef struct {……} *node;` mean?

Tags: c++

for example

```
typedef struct PNode { // PCB  
    struct PNode *next; // 定义指向下一个节点的指针

    char name[10];    // 定义进程名，并分配空间

    int Reach_Time;  //定义到达时间

    int Quantum;  //定义时间片

    int All_Time;    // 定义总运行时间

    int Runed_Time;    // 定义已运行时间

    char state;        // 定义进程状态 Ready / End 

    bool sign = true;  //用于排序中的标识
}*Proc; // 指向该PCB的指针
```

Note that there is a '*' before `Proc`.

I don't know what effort the '*' make.

Comment: It is C++ written by somebody who whishes they were programming in C. By the way, what are those comments saying?

Comment: To make it a pointer.

Comment: @5gon12eder (and guo): Looks like straight-up C to me, don't see any C++ in there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I only see C++ in the title and the tag. ;-)

Comment: @5gon12eder: Hence the "(and guo)" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proc` is a typedef for a `struct PNode*`.

The declaration is equivalent to:

```
struct PNode {
    struct PNode *next; 
    char name[10];  
    int Reach_Time; 
    int Quantum;  
    int All_Time;    
    int Runed_Time;  
    char state;      
    bool sign = true;
};

typedef struct PNode* Proc;
```

It's just taking a shortcut of declaring the `strut` and the typedef in one declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`*` at the end of a type expression means it's a pointer to the type described. So the `Proc` type is a pointer to a `Pnode` struct.

It's no different than if you'd written:

```
typedef int * IntPtr;
```

which defines an `IntPtr` type that means a pointer to an integer.

Note that it's generally considered poor style to create typedefs for pointers (except function pointers). It's better to keep the pointer explicit in the variable declarations. So just declare the structure, and declare variables like:

```
Pnode *my_pnode;
```

The main benefit of a pointer typedef is that you can declare multiple variables without repeating the `*`. So instead of

```
Pnode *proc1, *proc2, *proc3;
```

you can write:

```
Proc proc1, proc2, proc3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the start would not be there, `Proc` would be a `typedef` to struct PNode.

Now with the star present, `Proc` is `typedef`ed to PNode*, that means when you write `Proc` you mean a pointer to a PNode struct.